# Debugging Request pipeline in ASP.NET 5 (vNext) MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working with a MVC6 application in ASP.NET 5.  All is well, except one particular page that is taking about 45 seconds for the server to get a response back.

The controller isn't doing anything except sending the view:

```
public ActionResult Tables()
{
   return View();
}
```

The view is fairly large (188 kb), but it's all HTML and JS - there is no server-side @ razor markup in there which should be executing.

I'm trying to figure out exactly what's going on.

I can't seem to connect the profiler (maybe a vNext issue?), but it does look like, from the Visual Studio "Diagnostic Tools", that when that particular page is requested...

- the GC is thrashing for almost an entire minute while that page is being requested.
- CPU utilization is very high for the duration of the request
- Memory utilization is increased (semi?) permanently immediately following the request

[Arrows show start and end of page request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYNfs.png)

Any idea how to start debugging the root cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug with vNext RC1.

https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/635